# Como pido una palabra y la muestro letra por letra con javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Hola necesito crear una pagina simple que me pida una frase o palabra y luego me la muestra letra por letra ejemplo hola = h, o, l, a asi ya he probado muchas veces como por ejemplo esta

```
var palabras = prompt("Escriba su palabra");
let letras = palabras;
for ( i = 0; < letras; i++){
alert( str[0] );
}
```

O de otras como

```
var palabras = prompt("Escriba su palabra");
var letras = palabras.lenght
for (i = 0; i< letras; i++){
numeros = letras.chartAt(i)
alert(numeros)
}
```

pero tengo demasiados problemas como de que el prompt ni siquiera pregunta otra forma que use fue con return variable pero nada alguna manera de lograrlo u algo que debo cambiar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado:

Revisando ambos algoritmos, tienen algunos problemas de sintaxis, a continuación las versiones modificadas:

```js
var palabras = prompt("Escriba su palabra");
let letras = palabras;
for (i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
  alert(letras[i]);
}
```

```js
var palabras = prompt("Escriba su palabra");
var letras = palabras.length;
for (i = 0; i < letras; i++) {
  numeros = palabras.charAt(i);
  alert(numeros);
}
```

Espero haber contestado su pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias si definitivamente respondiste a mi duda me alegra saber que no esta tan lejos de mi planteamiento inicial te lo agradezco mucho